# Do a Nim regex modifier just like Perl one

Tags: pcre, nim-lang

How is Nim regex PCRE modifier done as in Perl itself is e.g.

```
/foobar/i
/ foo bar /x    
/foobar.*/s
```

etc ?

Please explain correctly doing such on Nim
Thanks much in advance

Comment: `(?i)foobar`, `(?x)foobar` and ``(?s)foobar``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I report the excellent answer provided by Hlaftaana to this same question on the forum: https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/8884

With `re` you supply a set of [RegexFlag](https://nim-lang.org/docs/re.html#RegexFlag) arguments to the [re function](https://nim-lang.org/docs/re.html#re%2Cstring), with `nre` you supply them [inside the regex](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nre.html#options).

**Example**:

```
import re
let reg1 = re("foo bar", {reIgnoreCase, reExtended})
# or
import nre
let reg2 = re"(?ix)foo bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using *inline modifiers*,

```
(?i)foobar
(?x)foobar
(?s)foobar
```

Or, *modifier groups*, which is especially handy when only a part of the pattern needs to be modified:

```
(?i:foobar)
(?x:foobar)
(?s:foobar)
```

See ["*Regex Modifiers—Turning them On*"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#other).